# Run-time error '13' on drop down column selector

Tags: excel, vba

I wasn't sure how to perform this function with excel formulas, so I tried VBA. I'm putting together a dashboard and I want a user to only see certain columns depending on what they choose in a drop down list.

My code works fine for its purpose; pick one item from the list, hides certain columns. The issue I'm experiencing is, that when I put a number in a random cell, say 17B, and fill to the right;
I get a

> run-time error '13' 'type mismatch'.

When I click out of the pop-up that informs me about the error, my code continues to work. But this constant pop up is a nuisance, what I am doing wrong? The run time error highlights line 2; the first part of the if/then statement. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "car" Then
        Application.Columns("C:I").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Application.Columns("J:BZ").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "bike" Then
        Application.Columns("J:P").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Application.Columns("C:I").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Application.Columns("Q:BZ").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Else
        Application.Columns("C:BZ").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you have combo box to select the values..then why do you have the code inside the worksheet_change action try it inside the combo_box select action.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is a combo_box? I don't see 'combo_box" in my lines above. Thank you

Comment: its your drop down activex object. Can you share the entire code as this block of code seems to be fine. also can you step run the code and check which line of code throws the error

Comment: The drop down list I have is actually just using the formulas; what you see here is all my code; everything typed into the vba. When I run the code, and the error pop-ups; it's the second line "If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "car" Then"    that is highlighted. My drop down list is just from the 'data validation' option in the 'data' tab; there is no code.

Comment: can you tell me what kind of data validation setting you have used?

Comment: Certainly. 'allow' is 'list' and source is 'car, bike'; those are the only two options I changed. Additionally, 'ignore blank' and 'in-cell dropdown' options are selected/clicked  - it's by default. I am using 2013 excel 64 bit

Comment: When Target is not a single cell its Value property is 2D array, so you can't compare that to a single value like "car"...  You need to exit if Target.Cells.Count > 1

Comment: Well my plan is the make the target values strings with two to five words; what would be the syntax for that without getting the error?

Comment: he is talking about the worksheet change getting a 2D array of cells instead of single cell.when you edit a cell and fill other cells,the worksheet change event is run,but the target parameter will contain an array of cells instead of a single cell  you want. So when you perform the .row .column  which are limited to single cell instead of an array of cells,the error pops up. it doesnt have anything to do with the values you specify it can be any number of values as long as the  worksheet_change is triggered only when a single cell is changed and the cell is "C1". Consider his solution for it.

Comment: Ok the solution is to add "exit if Target.Cells.Count > 1" somewhere? Where? Before and after what? I apologize for my ignorance, I don't use VBA much. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hell again, here is how tried to solve the problem. The fix did not work; the vba code now does not run. But I wanted to incorporate some ideas that worked for others, and now wish your feedback on how to make what I have below work.

I created a comobox, and used '$A$15:$A$16' as input range; - it's a list that has 'bike' and 'car'

For cell link, I used "$A$3"

The combo box inputs 1 and 2 only into "$A$3", and those are assigned to the two strings I have; 1 - is car, and 2 is bike.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then

If Target.Value = "1" Then
    Application.Columns("C:I").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Application.Columns("J:BZ").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

ElseIf Target.Value = "2" Then
    Application.Columns("J:P").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Application.Columns("C:I").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.Columns("Q:BZ").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Else
    Application.Columns("C:BZ").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            'start by unhiding all columns
            Me.Range("C:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            'then hide any which need hiding...
            If Target.Value = "car" Then
                Me.Range("J:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Target.Value = "bike" Then
                Me.Range("C:I,Q:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the process makes better sense. But it still does not work with my combo box which has a list of 'car' and 'bike' and inputs the related number into A3. How can I make your code work my comobox? I tried changing target values for car into 1, since the combo box outputs a 1 when car is chosen into A3. And 2 instead of bike. The box and the code are still not working together.

Comment: I thought you were using data Validation for your dropdown?